# Django models "blob" field

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-blob

I want to create a table like so -

> CREATE TABLE `trial_xml` (
>   `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `pid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `sid` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
>   **`data` blob,**
>   PRIMARY KEY (`soid`), 
>   KEY `suid_index` (`suid`) )
>   ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

my question is how do I set **"data"** field as **"blob"** in django's models.py ??

I mean what's the syntax?

UPDATE: I dont want to set `data` field as `longtext`. I want only `blob` datafield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's ORM has no field for binary large objects. Either use something like a `FileField`, or search for candidate field classes using a search engine.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using this simple field for 'mysql' backend, you can modify it for other backends

```
class BlobField(models.Field):
    description = "Blob"
    def db_type(self):
        return 'blob'
```

Comment: This is good for reading data. Unfortunately if you want to write BLOB data on Oracle backend you have to do something similar to this: http://code.google.com/p/cx-oracle-demos/source/browse/trunk/blob.py?r=11. Unfortunately I don't know how to incorporate it in django code.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, Django now has a proper BinaryField. It was added on Dec 13, 2012.

https://github.com/django/django/commit/8ee1eddb7e148de89aebde9e68da495633fc1ec9

The relevant documentation is available here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield